# Object reference error on chart load (Thread)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, charts

I am getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error on chart creation with threads, It was running fine without threads but I have to do it with threads, please help

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        trd = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
        trd.IsBackground = True
        trd.Start()

End sub
```

**Function**

```
 Private Sub ThreadTask()
        Dim Data As String() = Functions.runAnalyticsReportSample(100278)
        Functions.CredHolder(Session("User"), Session("Pw"))
        Dim split As String() = {""}

        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim colB As DataColumn = table.Columns.Add("A", GetType(String))
        Dim colD As DataColumn = table.Columns.Add("B", GetType(String))

        For Each line In Data

            split = line.Split(","c)

            Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()

            row.SetField(colB, split(0))
            row.SetField(colD, split(1))

            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next

        'Chart1.Series.Add("test")
        Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "A"
        Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "B"

        Chart1.Series("Series1").IsValueShownAsLabel = True
        Chart1.Series("Series1").IsVisibleInLegend = False


        Chart1.DataSource = table
        Chart1.DataBind()


    End Sub
```

Comment: Without knowing where the error occurs we can't possibly help. And the non thread version of your code would help

Comment: error occurs at    Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "A"

Comment: How did you declare `Chart1`.. By dragging a control onto the form, or by code - If by code, can you show the line of code used to declare the chart please?

Comment: Try moving the code that is in your Form_Load handler into a handler for Me.Shown. I thin that although the form is loaded, The controls probably haven't been actually instantiated by the time the Me.Load event fires.

Comment: I dont have Me.shown. this is vb website not a form

Comment: Hmm. Haven't played with Web pages yet. It's there an event that fires when the page has finished leading?

Comment: yes there is Me.loadcomplete but then I am getting this error "A chart element with the name 'Series1' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection'."

Comment: Odd. Sorry, I don't know enought about how web pages work to be able to give an answer - If you're using asp.net, it might help to add that tag to your question and include a [mcve]. Sorry I cant help much.